# How to convert Type to TEnum

Tags: c#

```
public enum eSAMPLE 
{
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    TypeC,
}
```

String table read and I got `Enum.Type`, and I want convert and apply to `listSample`.

```
public List<object> ExtenstionEnumParser(Type enumType, string targetStr)
{       
    List<object> dataList = new List<object>
    dataList.Add(Enum.Parse(enumType, targetStr));
}
```

I want this one:

```
List<eSAMPLE> listSmaple = ExtenstionEnumParser(enumType, "TypeA")
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the `Enum.Parse` method you're calling is this:

```
public static object Parse (Type enumType, string value);
```

It returns an `object`.

Your choice of the `ExtensionEnumParser` signature is the only one available:

```
public List<object> ExtenstionEnumParser(Type enumType, string targetStr)
```

So, to do your code int eh way you want to do it you'd need to call it like this:

```
List<eSAMPLE> listSmaple = ExtenstionEnumParser(enumType, "TypeA").OfType<eSAMPLE>().ToList();
```

But now you have two types, as such, the run-time type of `enumType` and the compile-time type of `eSAMPLE`. If you know the type at compile-time the the signature for the `Enum.Parse` you should use is this:

```
public static TEnum Parse<TEnum> (string value) where TEnum : struct;
```

So you could then write your method like this:

```
public List<TEnum> ExtenstionEnumParser<TEnum>(string targetStr) where TEnum : struct
{
    List<TEnum> dataList = new List<TEnum>();
    dataList.Add(Enum.Parse<TEnum>(targetStr));
    return dataList;
}
```

And you could run it like this:

```
List<eSAMPLE> listSmaple = ExtenstionEnumParser<eSAMPLE>("TypeA");
```